# Stop iCloud from restoring deleted files in IntelliJ

Tags: icloud

Sometimes I delete files directly in IntelliJ at the left hand project panel. For example classes or packages. I also clean the project after deleting the files. Unfortunately the deleted files appear again after few days or weeks. I guess they got restored from iCloud since some of the files have an ".icloud" appendix. How can I permanently delete these files?

Comment: I did not get good results with Java files in the cloud. No problems since moving all the code to a local directory. Backup in the Cloud? Just automate GitHub or GitLab commits.

Answer (score -1):

Since you get it back from iCloud your workspace is probably synced, so you could turn that off:
Settings -> Apple-ID -> iCloud -> iCloud Drive -> Options: disable the corresponding things (it probably will be Documents)

or:
move your workspace to a different place.

or if you still want iCloud to safe your stuff:
Try to delete the Files in Finder manually, or in Terminal. Maybe that will work.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! Yes I still would like to keep backups in the cloud. Will try the approach with the finder next time. There is even an option in  IntelliJ to show the file in finder. Will mark answer as correct if it works next time.